# xaml displays errors in lines that don't exist

Tags: xaml, xamarin

Visual Studio displays errors in my .xaml file. The lines of these errors are non existent. My code is 126 lines.

```
Severity      Code                 Line 
Error   XLS0112 Expected '}'.       139 
Error   XLS0112 Expected '''.       139 
Error   XLS0112 Expected ''.        139 
Error   XLS0112 Expected '
```

I can build the solution and run it.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting Visual Studio fixed the problem :)